# Filtering an AnyObject[ ] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following plist entries in a root dictionary:

[image: plist entry]

I've loaded it into a mutable dictionary:

```
var TabRecordKey = "TabRecord"
var TabRecordID: AnyObject  = []

        let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    println("Loaded DrinksData.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
    var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    if var dict = myDict {
        //loading values
        TabRecordID = dict.objectForKey(TabRecordKey)!
```

All lovely, I can append objects to TabRecordID, save them, print the record out in console.

But now I want to filter my TabRecordID to only display Items, say, for which TabRecord[i][0] = "Homer"

I've tried:

```
for i in 0..<TabRecord.count {
filter(TabRecordID) {TabRecord[i][0] = "Homer"}
}
```

But because TabRecordID is AnyObject, Swift replies:

> Generic parameter 'S' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type
>   'AnyObject'

I try:

```
let filteredArray = TabRecordID[i].filter() { TabRecordID[i][0] == "Homer"}
```

But get:

> 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'filter'

I try:

```
let filteredArray = (TabRecordID[i] as! Array).filter() { TabRecordID[i][0] == "Homer"}
```

But get:

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(() -> _)'

I know I'm missing something fundamental about type casting in Swift here, but it's driving me mental and I can't find a relevant question here that applies. Help a newb out, somebody, and show me the error of my ways. Be kind, I'm really trying here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  let pridicate = NSPredicate(block: { (obj, dic) -> Bool in
            let array = obj as! NSArray
            let str = array.firstObject as! String
            return str=="Homer"
        })
        let filterdResult = TabRecordID.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pridicate)
        println(filterdResult)
```

This will log

```
[(
Home,
Bear,
2
)]
```

Just for an example,you may use optional unwarpping in real case

Comment: Oh.My.God. You're a wizard. Now I have to hit the books as to why that worked, but it chucked out exactly the result I was hoping for. Cheers!